# Notepad ++ remove CR LF tag and find particular string and place data after it on a new line

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a file that I'm cleaning up, the file structure is kinda corrupted but there is a possible way of fixing.

**Problem**

```
1|firstname|lastname CRLF    
|address|Tel|1|firsname|lastname|address|Tel|
```

Theoretically this problem could be solved by removing the ***CRLF***  and find the second `|1|` in a line and move it to a new line. I tried doing this manually but I later noticed that the file is big and it's goning to take some time to cleanup.

I need an output to be like this:

```
1|firstname|lastname|address|Tel 
1|firstname|lastname|address|Tel
```

Comment: "Good day Bloggers" - this isn't a blog and majority of users aren't bloggers here(:, showing some respect by considering you audience would be a positive start for your question.

Comment: my sincere apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a two step solution:

1. remove line breaks:

   - open find / replace dialog (CTRL+H)
   - select "regular expression"
   - find what `\R`
   - Replace to  (nothing)
   - press "replace all"
2. insert line break before each `|1|`:

   - find what: `\|1\|`
   - replace to: `\n1|`

Comment: That was magic, thanks a lot Máté Juhász, it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

A single step could be:

- Find what: `^(.*)\R?(.*?)\|(?=1\|)`
- Replace with: `$1$2\n` or `$1$2\r\n` depending on platform
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

*Do not check `. matches newline`*